# Error : There is no parameter $1 in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have this method to insert a column in a database.
It works perfectly well in a MySQL database, but when the database is a PostgreSQL one I get the error in the question's title.

This is a small part of the method

```java
while (rs.next()) {
    String tableName = rs.getString(3);
    if (tableName.endsWith(this.getSuffix())) {
        tablesFound = true;
        if (!checkColumnsExists(connection, tableName, this.getColumnName(), databaseType)) {
            PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(getQuery(tableName));
            System.out.println("QUERY:"+getQuery(tableName));
            if (this.defaultValue != null) {
                System.out.println("DEFAULT VALUE: "+this.defaultValue);
                s.setString(1, this.defaultValue);
            }
            s.executeUpdate();
            logger.info("Column " + this.getColumnName() + " added to table " + tableName);
            columnsAdded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And when I print the query this is the result

```
QUERY:ALTER TABLE test2_transactions ADD COLUMN NEW_COLUMN_SUFFIX varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT ?
```

What am I doing wrong and I do it only happens in Postgre?

Comment: You can't pass the default value as parameter to ALTER TABLE, you have to specify a literal.

Comment: But it is working fine in MySQL

Comment: Why don't you use MySQL then?

Comment: You can apply a parameter on that specific location. Use SQL Injection instead.

Comment: @My application must support Postgre too. So the parameter works with MySQL but not with Postgre?

Comment: You need to provide the value as part of the string - that will also work with MySQL. In general you can't use a PreparedStatement with DDL statements in JDBC. MySQL's behaviour is non-standard (like so many things in MySQL)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I made the change but now I am getting the error `cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression`. Do you know what causes this?